# Allegro SCAN_DEPEND problems

Tags: visual-c++, allegro

I am trying to build a project with the allegro-msvc80-4.2.2 pre-built package.  I'm using Visual C++ Express Edition 2005 and have added the input library  alld.lib and am including allegro.h asp per these instructions:

http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Visual_C%2B%2B_Express_2005

When I compile, I get the fatal error:

> C1083: Cannot open include file:
>   'pc.h': No such file or directory

This is because the allegro platform header file "aldjgpp.h" tries to include the nonexistent file  (as well as others such as dpmi.h and unistd.h) if SCAN_DEPEND is undefined.

If I try defining SCAN_DEPEND, I get an error from alconfig.h saying "platform not supported."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error indicates that you are not using the proper header files. The header files that come with the pre-built files are set appropriately.

You should have an `include/allegro/platform/alplatf.h` file. For MSVC that should have one line:

```
#define ALLEGRO_MSVC
```

The best solution is to delete all instance of Allegro source from your computer, and redownload the file. Be sure to check your compiler's directories for stray headers. The following command, as run from the cmd.exe prompt, will help you find any files.

`dir /s c:\allegro.h`

If you continue to use the old header files, you may run across other problems.

Also, you may want to consider using Allegro 4.2.3, as it is the latest version of the 4.2 series. (Available at http://www.allegro.cc/files/.)